# Select random database record with a lowest value

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

very new to VB so apologies if I don't make a lot of sense.
I have a database of trivia questions with three fields: Question, Answer and Times Asked.
I want to be able to hit a button and receive a question from the database at random from among the records with the lowest Times Asked value, then add one to that record's Times Asked value.
Can anyone help me out? Here's what I've got so far:

```
Private DBCon As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; "Data Source=Trivia.accdb;")

Public Sub GenerateQuestion()

DBCon.Open()

'grab how many questions there are total
    Dim QuestionsQuery As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Questions"
    Dim QuestionsCmd As New OleDbCommand(QuestionsQuery, DBCon)
    Dim NumOfQuestions As Integer = QuestionsCmd.ExecuteScalar()

    'grab the lowest number from Times Asked
    Dim SeenQuery As String = "SELECT MIN(`Times`) FROM Questions"
    Dim SeenCmd As New OleDbCommand(SeenQuery, DBCon)
    Dim SeenReader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = SeenCmd.ExecuteReader
    SeenReader.Close()

 End Sub
```

This sub is called from a button on another form and when I click the button I get an exception for no data existing in the row/column. Even if I manage to get this value though I have no idea what the next step is with actually grabbing a random question from among the minimum Times values and adding one to the Times value for that question.

For reference here is the table I'm working with atm:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVfia.png

EDIT: To anyone finding this in the future here is the code that fixed the problem:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
   Dim rng As New Random
Dim connection As OleDb.OleDbConnection

Private Function GetQuestionWithAnswer() As Tuple(Of String, String)
    'Use XML literals for the SQL statements.
    Dim selectSql = <sql>
                    SELECT *
                    FROM Questions
                    WHERE Times =
                    (
                        SELECT MIN(Times)
                        FROM Questions
                    )
                </sql>
    Dim updateSql = <sql>
                    UPDATE Questions
                    SET Times = @Times
                    WHERE ID = @ID
                </sql>

    Using connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=Trivia.accdb;")
        Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(selectSql.Value, connection)
        Dim updateCommand = New OleDbCommand(updateSql.Value, connection)

        With updateCommand.Parameters
            .Add("@Times", OleDbType.Integer, 0, "Times")
            .Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer, 0, "ID")
        End With

        adapter.UpdateCommand = updateCommand

        Dim table As New DataTable

        'Getall the questions that have been asked the fewest number of times.
        adapter.Fill(table)

        'Select a question at random.
        Dim record = table.Rows(rng.Next(table.Rows.Count))

        'Increment the number of times the question has been asked and save the change.
        record("Times") = CInt(record("Times")) + 1
        adapter.Update(table)

        'Package up the selected question.
        LblQuestion.Text = record(1)
        Return Tuple.Create(CStr(record("Question")), CStr(record("Answer")))

    End Using
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the use of Rand in Mysql:http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/

If you use Rand, it is not necessary to Select questions which are not shown mostly. It will be balanced if you use only Rand.